# How to convert this logarithm into this form?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

How to convert this logarithm:

```
Log[Log[2]]/Log[2]
```

into this form:

```
Log[2, Log[2]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the property

[image]

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False}]
expr = Log[Log[2]]/Log[2]
expr /. Log[x_]/Log[a_] :> Log[a, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But we have to set the system option in place before to prevent Mathematica from auto-simplify it.

Comment: Does setting this option only take effect for current session, or will it be stored in a config file?

Comment: @Ruslan this option is for current session. You can always put it your ini file so it is activated automatically each time you start Mathematica.

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = Log[Log[2]]/Log[2];
expr /. Log[x_]/Log[a_] :> Defer[Log[a, x]]
```

> Log[2, Log[2]]